# Was it ever revealed what pedaling the bicycles in the second episode was doing?

Tags: black-mirror

I'm going to assume they were probably some sort of turbine...electricity...something, but I'd prefer to know for sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_Million_Merits) states:

> most citizens make a living pedaling exercise bikes all day in order
>   to generate power for their environment

This is explicitly referred to by the judge during Abi's *Hot Shot* audition:

> "Who do you think is powering that spotlight? Millions of people,
>   that's who. All of them out there right now. Putting in an honest day
>   on the bike while you stand in the light they're generating..."